# Sightly to compare number with value from dialog

Tags: html, adobe, aem, sightly, htl

I want to be able to read the value that I have set in the dialog and use it in Sightly to control what section of code is shown.  When I have tried using the code below I have been receiving this error "Operands are not of the same type : comparison is supported for numbers only". 
I have tried so many different fixes and have found nothing that works nor any documentation for it. Is context = 'number' not the correct syntax or is there anything else I have to add?

IN THE DIALOG

```
<number
      jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
      sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
      fieldLabel="Select Amount of Delivery Options"
      name="./number"
      value = "4" >
      <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
          <four
               jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
               text="Four"
               value= "4" />
         <three
               jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
               text="Three"
               value= "3" />
         <two
             jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
             text="Two"
             value= "2" />
         <one
             jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
             text="One"
             value= "1" />
 </items> </number>
```

IN THE HTL

```
<sly data-sly-test="${properties.podnumber @ context = 'number' >= 1}">
```

Answer (score 2):

first, your dialog has `name="./number` and in your HTL you use `properties.podnumber` they do not match.

To answer your question: there is no way to do this with sightly alone, the `context` option is only for rendering (XSS protection) and does not change the value.

Your best bet is to use a sling model, something like

> I assume your dialog will have `name="podNumber"`

```
@Model(
    adaptables = {Resource.class},
    defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public interface MyModel {

  @Inject
  int getPodNumber();

}
```

Sling will then convert that value to an integer you can use in your comparison. so you can add your model with `data-sly-use.myModel="package.name.MyModel"` then use it:

`<sly data-sly-test="${myModel.podNumber >= 1}">`

> By the way, all the values in your dropdown are larger than or equal to 1.

**NOTE:** as Florian suggested in the comment below, you should use boolean checks in the model, instead of having to compare values in HTL. for example:

```
@Model(
    adaptables = {Resource.class},
    defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
public class MyModel {

  @Inject
  int podNumber;

  boolean isLargerThanOne(){
     return podNumber > 1;
  }
```

Comment: While I dig the model approach, I would consider to implement boolean properties to inspect the state of the model, keeping the state management out of the HTL script.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic I completely agree with you on that one. From a "good practice" standpoint, it makes absolute sense. However, I was spcifically answering the "comparison" question in this case. I'll add a note anyway.

Comment: `true`, I was too much into how I would solve the problem, not how the answer should be answered.